# Developer Preview/Pilot Features in a managed package

Tags: managed-package

I'm thinking specifically of the new TYPEOF clause in a soql statement, but my question refers to any developer preview or pilot feature.

Is the usage and inclusion of this feature into a managed package acceptable, or will it cause installation errors?

Comment: Not an answer but from past experience I'd try and avoid this unless you have partner premier support. If you don't the support for any issues that do arise is generally weak at best, or a flat denial of support for using a non-GA feature at worst.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your target org isn't of the right version I'm almost certain it is going to fail.

Pilot stuff does change, so even if its working now, it may change radically come GA and you'll need to rework it.  (The Apex REST API comes to mind)

I got burnt with using @RemoteAction when it was in preview and had to pull it all out again when it appeared that it had some serious bugs, as a general rule now I don't do any preview stuff for a customer unless its genuinely a Proof of Concept style thing.